# Django filtering and querying: do it in views.py, template, or filters?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-template-filters

So I am working on a small Django project, which for the moment doesn't require optimization. But to prepare for the future, I'd like to know a bit more about the three approaches.

For instances, as part of the models, I have `User` and `UserProfile`, `Transaction`.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = ...
    email = ...

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='profile')
    photo = models.URLField(...)
    ...

class Transaction(models.Model):
    giver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="transactions_as_giver")
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='transactions_as_receiver')
    ...
```

I frequently need to do something like "return `transactions` that the `request.user` is `giver` or `receiver`", or "return the profile photo of a user". I have several choices, for instance to get a list of pending transactions and `photo`s of both parties, I can do it at `views.py` level:

1.

```
#views.py
transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(Q(giver=request.user)|Q(receiver=request.user))
for transaction in transactions:
    giver_photo = transactions.giver.profile.all()[0].photo
    # or first query UserProfile by
    # giver_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=transaction.giver),
    # then giver_photo = giver_profile.photo
    # 
    # Then same thing for receiver_photo
    transaction['giver_photo'] = giver_photo
    ...
```

2. Or I can do it more on `template` level:

   ```
   # some template
   <!-- First receive transactions from views.py without photo data -->
   {% for t in transactions %}
   {{t.giver.profile.all.0.photo}}, ...
   {% endfor %}
   ```
3. Or I can move some or even all of the above stuffs into `filters.py`

   ```
   # some template
   {{ for t in request.user|pending_transactions }}
   {{ t.giver|photo  }} {{ t.receiver|photo }}
   {{ endfor }}
   ```

where `photo` and `pending_transactions` are roughly the same code in original `views.py` but moved to a filter.

So I wonder is there a best practice/guide line on how to choose which approach?

From Django documentation, lower level is faster, and therefore 2. 3. should be slower than 1; but how about comparing the 2. and 3.?

In getting a user photo, which of the two should be recommended, `transactions.giver.profile.all()[0].photo` OR `profile = UserProfile.objects.get(...) --> photo = profile.photo`?

Comment: Check it out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-invent-a-programming-language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this logic into models and managers.  Views and templates must be as short as possible.

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    def transactions(self):
        return Transaction.objects.filter(Q(giver=self)|Q(receiver=self))

    def photo(self):
        return self.profile.all().first().photo
```

So the template will be:

```
{% for t in request.user.transactions %}
    {{ t.giver.photo  }} {{ t.receiver.photo }}
{% endfor %}
```

My experience says that business logic in model as much easier to test, support and reuse than in the views/templates.

Comment: I see. So chaining `return self.profile.all()...` should be recommended over `profile = UserProfile.objects.get(...);return profile.photo`?

Comment: In most cases yes.  BTW, I suggest to change relation between `UserProfile` and `User` from `ForeignKey` to `OneToOne`.  This will allow you to acces to user's profile as simple as `user.profile` instead of `user.profile.all()[0]`